# Is possible to drag a Chrome window using Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, google-chrome

I would like to have a div inside of a HTML page that on mouse down and move the entire Chrome window to be dragged.

Is this possible? My project will run locally, so if it's not possible I guess that there is an alternative using another application that will set the Chrome window position.

The server side is on Nodejs.

As OS, I use Linux.

Comment: What do you mean move the entire window? You mean create a new application window or you mean make the `<div>` act like a dialog box inside the browser?

Comment: @Phillip I mean the browser window. I know that Chrome has an API, but I don't know if such a thing is possible...

Comment: What have you tried until now? Did you try [window.moveTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.moveTo)

Comment: No, I have no idea where must I start. I tried `window.moveTo(1, 1)` but it doesn't work... Seems that this would be perfectly for me if it would work.

Comment: @winner_joiner I've just read that *You can't move a window or tab that wasn’t created by `window.open`.* This is great. It works. But is there another function that moves a window with tabs?

Comment: What do you want to use this for?

Comment: I didnt see any function that could do this, but the best place to find out ist the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/), there they exyplain most of the functions available. If you cant find it there, it probably doesnt exist. Good Luck.

Comment: @MrLister I am imaging a pseudo window build only with CSS, HTML & JS that is inside of a browser window. I want that when *trying to drag* my pseudo HTML window from the browser, the entire browser window to be dragged in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research I found that the browser opened popup is possible to be moved using `window.moveTo(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are the absolute coordinates of the monitor screen.

I created a Github repository where I pushed my code. Probably I will write a small jQuery/pure js plugin that will be very easy to use for this scope.

So, this is the repository: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/drag-popup

Don't forget to disable popup blocker...

I will update this answer when there will be changes.